# Stop event propagation after a certain child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unsure if I framed the question correctly, I have the following code.

```js
var ul = $( '#root' );

ul.on( 'click', 'li', function( e ) {
  console.log( e.currentTarget )
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li><div>Some Text</div></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Upon clicking any of the `li` items, the console outputs `li`, even for the 2nd `li` item.

How can I use plain JavasScript to achieve the same? Tolimit the event target to `li` and not go beyond that to any of the children?

I tried this:

```
var root = document.getElementById( 'root' );

root.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
  console.log( e.target )
});
```

But upon clicking the 2nd `li` item, it logs `div`

Comment: The second `li` logs `<li>…</li>` for me, not `<div>`, in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @Connum, with the plain JavaScript code it logs `<li>` for you? That's strange.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were referring to the snippet code!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make this work in plain JS you can call `closest()` from the `e.target` to determine if the event was raised by an `li`, or the child of an `li`:

```js
var li = document.getElementById('root');

root.addEventListener('click', function(e) {      
  var li = e.target.closest('li');
  if (li)
    console.log(li.tagName); // a little redundant, but purely for demo purposes
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
      <div>Some Text</div>
    </li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note that `closest()` is not natively supported in IE, but there is a [polyfill available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill).

Comment: Is this how even jQuery does it? Just curious. I read how the event flows from the root to children and back, in that case is it possible to trace the nodes where the event have passed through?

Comment: I'm not certain how jQuery does it exactly, but the pattern will be similar to this. `I read how the event flows from the root to children and back` Just to be clear, the event only goes up the DOM tree, so there is no 'going back'. `is it possible to trace the nodes where the event have passed through?` Yes, you could recurse through the DOM from the clicked element up as far as required.

Answer (score 2):

When anything inside the `ul` is clicked, you might just find the `.closest` `<li>`, and log it:

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');

root.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const possibleLi = e.target.closest('li');
  if (!possibleLi) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(possibleLi);
});
```

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <ul>clicking here should do nothing
    <li></li>
    <li>
      <div>Some Text</div>
    </li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i think his code doing same. I think he want that when he click on second li it will not fire. I am also not fully clear

Comment: @CertainPerformace, is this how even jQuery does it? Just curious. I read how the event flows from the root to children, in that case is it possible to trace the nodes where the event have passed through?